# Use a different path for Varnish Backend

Tags: varnish

I'm using Varnish 2.1 (on Fastly if that matters), and I want to do something kind of weird:

I want to take a request to example.com/123456, and have fastly fetch the content from A_Backend, but on the path /longpath/123456.

Right now what I'm doing is in vcl_recv, I'm setting the backend, and returning pass. Then in vcl_pass, trying to rewrite the bereq.path.

Now I just end in a redirect loop. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

set req.url = "/longpath" + req.url

or regsuball.

Comment: This doesn't actually work because it changes the request, not what path is sent to the backend.

Comment: Don't do it in vcl_pass, do it in recv. It'll work if you put it in recv, I've done it before.